# How to insert a new field into a table which related to another table?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have two tables in MS Access 2013.

There are some conditions:
1. Part can only be withdrawn after serviced.
2. After certain time, part will be returned for service again.
3. Part can be recycled.

### tblService:

(ID is the primary key)

```
ID  PART_ID SERV_DATE
1    A0001  11/1/2013
2    A0001  11/13/2013
3    A0001  11/25/2013
4    B0001  11/26/2013
5    C0001  12/1/2013
6    C0001  12/10/2013
7    C0001  12/20/2013
8    A0001  12/21/2013
```

### tblWithdraw:

(ID is the primary key)

```
ID PART_ID DRAWN_DATE DRAWN_REASON DRAWN_TO
1   A0001  11/6/2013       PM         601
2   A0001  11/20/2013    120 PM       603
3   A0001  11/30/2013  REPLACEMENT    605
4   C0001  12/2/2013      30 PM       701
5   C0001  12/15/2013    180 PM       702
6   B0001  12/18/2013      PM         801
7   A0001  12/25/2013     60 PM       502
```

I'd like to insert a new field, **SERVICE_ID**, into tblWithdraw, look like this:

```
ID PART_ID DRAWN_DATE DRAWN_REASON DRAWN_TO SERVICE_ID
1   A0001  11/6/2013       PM         601       1
2   A0001  11/20/2013    120 PM       603       2
3   A0001  11/30/2013  REPLACEMENT    605       3
4   C0001  12/2/2013      30 PM       701       5
5   C0001  12/15/2013    180 PM       702       6
6   B0001  12/18/2013      PM         801       4
7   A0001  12/25/2013     60 PM       502       8
```

which **SERVICE_ID** is the **ID** in **tblService**.

However, when I tried codes below in the query:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblWithdraw ( SERVICE_ID ) SELECT ID
```

FROM tblService;

It gave me:

```
ID PART_ID DRAWN_DATE DRAWN_REASON DRAWN_TO SERVICE_ID
1   A0001  11/6/2013       PM         601
2   A0001  11/20/2013    120 PM       603
3   A0001  11/30/2013  REPLACEMENT    605
4   C0001  12/2/2013      30 PM       701
5   C0001  12/15/2013    180 PM       702
6   B0001  12/18/2013      PM         801
7   A0001  12/25/2013     60 PM       502
8                                               1
9                                               2
10                                              3
11                                              4
12                                              5
13                                              6
14                                              7
15                                              8
```

Or codes below:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblWithdraw (SERVICE_ID) SELECT ID FROM tblService WHERE tblService.PART_ID =tblWithdraw.PART_ID;
```

The system can't recognize **tblWithdraw.PART_ID**.

Can anyone correct my codes or give me answer or direct me to the solution? Thanks!

Comment: INSERT INTO tblWithdraw ( SERVICE_ID )
SELECT ID
FROM tblService
WHERE tblService.PART_ID = tblWithdraw.PART_ID;, by this line what you     are trying to achieve

Comment: @Suganthan Post this as an answer.

Comment: @Zev Spitz Is it a valid code ? I couldn't able to understand the OP

Comment: @Suganthan You're right; the OP needs to clarify which `SERVICE_ID` should be updated for each record.

Comment: Thanks for all of your replies. Initially I do not have SERVICE_ID in tblWithdraw. Later on, I realised that I required the field for joining tblService and tblWithdraw. However, I already have few ten thousands of records which I can't add the SERVICE_ID one by one. Therefore, I require a query that can help me to tabulate the SERVICE_ID by itself. After that, when an item is withdrawn, SERVICE_ID will be updated for each record by a VBA. Any code is welcome, as long as it can tabulate the SERVICE_ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have discovered, INSERT statements always add new rows to a table. You want to UPDATE existing rows using something like this:

```sql
UPDATE tblWithdraw
SET SERVICE_ID = DLookup("ID","tblService","PART_ID='" & PART_ID & "' AND SERV_DATE=#" & Format(DMax("SERV_DATE","tblService","PART_ID='" & PART_ID & "' AND SERV_DATE<=#" & Format(DRAWN_DATE,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "#"),"yyyy-mm-dd") & "#")
```

It uses `DMax()` to find the most recent SERV_DATE that precedes a given DRAWN_DATE, then does a `DLookup()` to find the corresponding [tblService].[ID], and then plugs it into the SERVICE_ID column in [tblWithdraw].

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks for your explanation. Your answer is great and your explanation is very clear. Thank you!