# Update field of Table B when date of Table B >= date of Table A

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have two tables in MS Access 2013.

There are some conditions:

> 1. Part can only be withdrawn after serviced.
> 2. After certain time, part will be returned for service again.
> 3. Part can be serviced, withdrawn, returned and serviced, withdrawn, returned on the same day too.

### Table of Service:

(ID is the primary key)

```
ID PART_ID SERVICE_DATE
1   A0001   01/05/2014
2   A0002   02/05/2014
3   A0003   03/05/2014
4   A0004   04/05/2014
5   A0005   05/05/2014
6   A0001   06/05/2014
7   A0002   07/05/2014
```

### Table of Withdraw:

(ID is the primary key)

```
ID PART_ID DRAW_DATE
1   A0001  02/05/2014
2   A0002  03/05/2014
3   A0003  04/05/2014
4   A0001  07/05/2014
5   A0002  08/05/2014
```

I updated **SERVICE_ID** in the table of **Withdraw** using code below:

```sql
UPDATE WITHDRAW SET SERVICE_ID = DLookup("ID","SERVICE","PART_ID ='" & PART_ID & "' AND SERVICE_DATE =#" & DMax("SERVICE_DATE","SERVICE","PART_ID ='" & PART_ID & "' AND SERVICE_DATE <=#" & DRAW_DATE & "#") & "#");
```

with the help of **[Gord Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309834/how-to-insert-a-new-field-into-a-table-which-related-to-another-table)**, which the **SERVICE_ID** is the **ID** in table of **Service**.

It works well when the date of Withdraw is at least one day **later** than the date of Service, as shown as below:

Table of Service:

```
ID PART_ID SERVICE_DATE
1   A0001   01/05/2014
2   A0002   02/05/2014
3   A0003   03/05/2014
4   A0004   04/05/2014
5   A0005   05/05/2014
6   A0001   06/05/2014
7   A0002   07/05/2014
```

Table of Withdraw:

```
ID PART_ID DRAW_DATE  SERVICE_ID
1   A0001  02/05/2014     1
2   A0002  03/05/2014     2
3   A0003  04/05/2014     3
4   A0001  07/05/2014     6
5   A0002  08/05/2014     7
```

However, when that date is **similar**, it is unable to capture the **SERVICE_ID** correctly.

### Situation 1:

Table of Service:

```
ID PART_ID SERVICE_DATE
1   A0001   01/05/2014
2   A0002   01/05/2014
3   A0003   01/05/2014
4   A0004   01/05/2014
5   A0005   01/05/2014
6   A0001   01/05/2014
7   A0002   01/05/2014
```

Table of Withdraw:

```
ID PART_ID DRAW_DATE  SERVICE_ID
1   A0001  01/05/2014     1
2   A0002  01/05/2014     2
3   A0003  01/05/2014     3
4   A0001  01/05/2014     1       (problem)
5   A0002  01/05/2014     2       (problem)
```

### Situation 2:

Table of Service:

```
ID PART_ID SERVICE_DATE
1   A0001   01/05/2014
2   A0002   01/05/2014
3   A0003   01/05/2014
4   A0004   01/05/2014
5   A0005   01/05/2014
6   A0001   20/05/2014
7   A0002   25/05/2014
```

Table of Withdraw:

```
ID PART_ID DRAW_DATE  SERVICE_ID
1   A0001  20/05/2014     6       (problem)
2   A0002  23/05/2014     2
3   A0003  24/05/2014     3
4   A0001  20/09/2014     6
5   A0002  08/05/2015     7
```

I have a very little knowledge in SQL. I have no idea what condition I have to add in order to get the result I want. Does anybody can help? Thanks!

Comment: Could it be something as simple as using `... AND SERVICE_DATE <# ...` instead of `... AND SERVICE_DATE <=# ...` in the existing UPDATE query? (That is, using `<` instead of `<=`.)

Comment: Hi! Glad to see you again! I have tried your suggestion. Changing to < solves problem in Situation 2, but not in Situation 1.

Comment: If parts can be withdrawn and returned more than once in the same day then perhaps tracking by date alone is insufficient and you should consider tracking by date and time.

Comment: I totally agreed. But the past data only captured date. Addition of SERVICE_ID is just to make the other form works correctly. I'm not able to amend few thousand records. Thanks anyway!